# Magento - Import Products - getAdapter is returning null

Tags: magento, import

I'm working on importing products through cron job..At first it ran well and imported about 400 odd records in the database. But later on I found out that we need to add external images to all the products which are going to upload henceforth. So I did a google search and used the solution as pointed out in this url http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-import-product-images-from-external-url-in-magento/ ( used the Magento 1.6.1 solution ).

I had created a separate file in my local file as directed.But the product import is now not working and I'm getting $batchModel->getAdapter() as null.Further I deleted the local file from my local Adapter Directory. Also I'm now trying to import normal images i.e which are in the same domain. Following is a snippet of my import process:

```
 $profile->run();
  $batchModel = Mage::getSingleton('dataflow/batch');
  var_dump($batchModel->getId());
  if ($batchModel->getId()) {
    var_dump($batchModel->getAdapter());
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding :

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->setParam('files', $fileName);
```

at the beginnig of my script

where $fileName is name for my "import.csv"

```
(view app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php)
```